# tags for google search in djnago

Tags: html, django

How can i make tags for google search to my domain name for example this is the domain name:

> [www.BuildSoftApp.ir](http://www.BuildSoftApp.ir)

when some one search like, build soft or make app and etc google find this domain name, in word press when we making a page there is an option for add tags for search engines i think it is called keywords but iam not sure,
 i don't know how can i do this in `django` or it is possible or not,

if there is a way to do this please tell me.

Comment: Do you mean meta tags like title, keywords or description?

Comment: i have no idea can you explain?

Comment: but i heard some things about keywords when some body searching

Answer (score 0):

1. What you need is for Google to index your site and 'discover' the right content
2. To do this, you need to add the `meta tags for description, content`  to your html page. See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML).
3. If your site has dynamic content or is large, you should also create a [sitemap](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/overview) for your website and submit this to Google and other search engines
4. If you also want to be easily found on Twitter, Facebook and other media sites (and also for easy sharing/discovery on those sites), you need to add the proper tags from the [OG Graph](https://ogp.me/). Actually, the OG Graph also enriches the information Google displays about your site